# jScrollPane doesn't initialize properly due to wrong width and height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-jscrollpane

Please look at this page. I'm struggling several hours to understand what is wrong. But without success. Click on firm history. The text should be scrollable. There is enough text to be scrollable.

http://test.dhmdesign.com/studio/about/overview

jScrollPane is initialized in custom.js on ajaxComplete event.

I think jScrollPane doesn't detect correctly width and height, the result is isScrollableV - false (in jScrollPane plugin).

Answer (score 0):

By adding a couple of line breaks here and there, I noticed that you initialize the jScrollPane before the popup shows up.

Since the content is not yet on screen, jscrollpane can't get the height of the text thus not showing the scrollbars.

I've had a problem similar to this before

Could you try to show the popup and then initialize jscollpane?

Comment: You could try using [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)'s `onComplete` callback. I'm not sure if that waits long enough for the DOM to initialize in the popup, but it's probably the quickest solution for your current code if it does.

Comment: @thirdender I also thought of that but from what I saw, when you click on the link, colorbox opens and then the content is loaded. I don't think it would work in his case but I may be mistaken!

Comment: yeah, wasn't sure :-p Figured it was a five minute test, and if it doesn't work, 30 minutes of coding…